# Never + past simple. Help me understand the meaning please

Tags: grammar, meaning, past-simple

I'm reading and learning an example dialog and can't understand the meaning of this phrase:
You sit there staring at the screen and taking to yourself. **You never even combed your hair.** You look like a madman

"Never ... combed" means "didn't ... combed"?
If yes, why didn't they write "didn't"? Why we need "never" here?

Thank you much

Comment: It's just a way of adding extra emphasis and a sense of reproach to "You haven't combed your hair". It doesn't mean that the person has never in their life combed their hair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In such a context, **never** can be thought of the same as **did not** or **didn't**. We use it when we wish to *intensify* the emotional quality of the statement. **Never** is frequently paired with **even** when we wish to intensify the statement *a lot*.

You example communicates an emotional feeling kind of like this:

> You did not comb your hair, and this failure disappoints me.

But notice that **never** continues to function as an adverb. Unlike "did not," it does not change the form of the verb that follows: the verb must still be conjugated in the ordinary fashion. The following pair illustrates the difference:

> He did not comb his hair. [*comb* is a bare infinitive following "did"]
> He never combed his hair. [*combed* is a finite verb with the past tense marker "ed."]

The following is wrong:

> *He never comb his hair.

Obviously, **never** can be used in the ordinary sense of *at no time*. The distinction will usually be clear from context:

> Friend: Have you ever been to the park?
> Me: No, I never have. [At no time *in my entire life* have I been to the park.]
>
> Friend: You're old enough. Did you ever see the Beatles in concert?
> Me: No, I never did. [At no time *in my entire life* did I ever see the Beatles, and I never will.]
>
> Police officer: A crime was committed at the park yesterday. Were you there?
> Me: At the park? No. I never even left the house. [At no time *yesterday* did I leave the house.]
>
> Mom: Did you speak to your father yesterday?
> Me: Nope. I never even texted him. [At no time *yesterday* did I text him.]

Comment: Jeffery Carney thank you so much for your explanation. It's very useful for me

Comment: Jeffrey sorry for one more question. I didn't understand what does the word order mean in your example kind of like this: At no time in my entire life have I been to the park. Could you tell me please why does "have" go before the subject? It's not a question, is it?

Comment: @Bari The accepted answer to **[this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267854/can-we-or-we-can/267861)** explains it well. The linked **[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion)** at Wikipedia is also informative.

Comment: thanks a million again)

Comment: Then there is the additional scenario where the "never" is followed by a verb in the present tense (i.e. "He never combs his hair"), which turns it into a form of "does not"